# Testing for pipe or console standard input with ARGF

Tags: ruby, input, command-line-arguments

I have written a script that I would like to take input either from a pipe or by providing a filename as an argument. ARGF makes it easy to deal with this flexibly, except in the incorrect usage cases where *neither* is provided, in which case STDIN is opened and it hangs until the user inputs something on the console.

I would like to catch this incorrect usage to display an error message and exit the program, but I haven't been able found a way. `ARGF.eof?` seemed like a possible candidate, but it also hangs until some input is received.

Is there a simple way for Ruby to discriminate between STDIN provided by a pipe and one from the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use

```
$stdin.tty?
```

for example

```
$ ruby -e 'puts $stdin.tty?'
> true
$ echo "hello" |  ruby -e 'puts $stdin.tty?'
> false
```